# Can not start Oracle after installation

Tags: libraries, oracle-database

I'm using Lenovo G580 under intel i5 third generation with 4GB RAM. I'm trying to install [Oracle 11g standard edition](https://www.google.co.in/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CDYQFjAA&url=http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/database/enterprise-edition/downloads/&ei=7_-7Uby5Eo7yrQelqoGIBA&usg=AFQjCNG4YggO44zqoE9o5XWBYw_MMQJ1RQ&sig2=rSXfZ8D3Eg902xhDCxNszg&bvm=bv.47883778,d.bmk)

After completing all pre installation and post installation procedures, when I started sqlplus I got an error, something like this:

```
sqlplus: error while loading shared libraries: libsqlplus.so: cannot open shared object file: No such file or directory
```

I've searched many websites, but I didn't get clear way to rectify this. What do I need to do to get rid of this error?

Answer (score 1):

#### Potential Issue #1

Your issue is most likely being caused by sqlplus' .so libraries not being on the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`. You can set this environment variable so that it's correct:

```
 # /path/to/11g/folder/where/sqlpluslib
 $ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/path/to/11g/folder/where
```

#### Potential Issue #2

Based on your comments on my answer and on @maxschlepzig answer I would surmise that your installation wasn't done correctly. I would suggest doing the installation again. Oracle can be a bit tricky to install.

Here are some instructions specifically geared for 11gR2 and Ubuntu 12.04.

- [HOWTO install Oracle 11g on Ubuntu Linux 12.04 (Precise Pangolin) 64bits](http://www.makina-corpus.org/blog/howto-install-oracle-11g-ubuntu-linux-1204-precise-pangolin-64bits)

Comment: ya even i thought this might be the problem but this is not.see my ENV variables...   export ORACLE_HOME=u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
export PATH=$PATH:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/bin
export ORACLE_OWNR=oracle
export ORACLE_SID=orcl
LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib:/lib:/usr/lib;
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib;
export CLASSPATH

Comment: @Thiyagu, adding `/lib:/usr/lib` to `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` should not be necessary - the dynamic linker lookups by default in those directories.

Comment: ok...but even-though i removed those links form my ENV,but still 'm getting the error.

Comment: @Thiyagu, sure - they are just redundant - unnecessary.

Comment: @maxschlepzig:ya i've removed..new ENV is LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
export LD_LIBRARY_PATH
CLASSPATH=$ORACLE_HOME/jlib:$ORACLE_HOME/rdbms/jlib;
export CLASSPATH

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, Oracle does not set the runtime linker path of the sqlplus binary.

As a quick workaround you can set the `LD_LIBRARY_PATH`:

```
$ export LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$ORACLE_HOME/lib
```

On my Cento-OS system the values are:

```
$ echo -e $ORACLE_HOME'\n'$LD_LIBRARY_PATH
/home/juser/app/juser/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1
/home/juser/app/juser/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib
```

You can verify if the library path was set correctly via:

```
$ ldd $ORACLE_HOME/bin/sqlplus
```

Which should output something like:

```
[..]
    libsqlplus.so => /home/juser/app/juser/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libsqlplus.so (0x00007fc58e70f000)
    libclntsh.so.11.1 => /home/juser/app/juser/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1/lib/libclntsh.so.11.1 (0x00007fc58c0e3000)
```

Comment: i got like this: linux-gate.so.1 =>  (0xb76e8000)
 libsqlplus.so => not found
 libclntsh.so.11.1 => not found
 libnnz11.so => not found
 libdl.so.2 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libdl.so.2 (0xb76c7000)
 libm.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libm.so.6 (0xb769b000)
 libpthread.so.0 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0 (0xb7680000)
 libnsl.so.1 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libnsl.so.1 (0xb7666000)
 libc.so.6 => /lib/i386-linux-gnu/libc.so.6 (0xb74bb000)
 /lib/ld-linux.so.2 (0xb76e9000)

Comment: @Thiyagu, hm, looks like your `ORACLE_HOME` is not set correctly - you have to verify where the needed shared libraries were installed, e.g. `find $ORACLE_HOME -name 'libclntsh.so*'`

Comment: no dude..i've checked oracle_home,that value is correct.. installation path:/u01/app/oracle/product/11.2.0/dbhome_1

Comment: while installing Oralce11g standard edition i faced an error  "Install Oracle fails: error in invoking target 'client_sharedlib'" i just skipped it and continue the process.dose this cause an error?

Comment: @Thiyagu, probably - perhaps the `libclntsh.so` & co. shared library files just weren't copied then. You can verify this via the above `find` command.

Comment: ya when i run the above find command i did't get any output!

Comment: when i Googled about the client_sharedlib issue,most of them said software and hardware compatibility.but here not this case..'m using Oracle 32 bit under Ubuntu 32 bit but still 'm getting this error

Comment: @Thiyagu, if `find` can't find any matching files it outputs nothing. That means that the needed shared library is not there, i.e. it was not installed. No wonder that the dynamic linker can't find it then. Regarding the install error message - since it is a separate issue you should ask a new question for it. A hint: oracle writes a install logfile - perhaps it contains more details.

Comment: so that installation error cause this problem right?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9249/discussion-between-maxschlepzig-and-thiyagu)